# Animation is applied to replaced content when using a ternary operator in react-redux

Tags: css, reactjs, internet-explorer, sass, react-redux

I am using a ternary operator to show a loading spinner before replacing it with the actual content. The code below works correctly in Firefox and Chrome however, the animation continues to happen on the replaced content in IE.

This will cause the replaced content to spin like the loader:

```
<div className="wrapper">
    {isFetching ? <div className="loader large" /> : <div>{children}</div>}
</div>
```

This fixes the issue:

```
<div className="wrapper">
    {isFetching && <div className="loader large" />}
    {!isFetching && <div>{children}</div>}
</div>
```

This also fixes the issue (prevent self closing div):

```
<div className="wrapper">
    {isFetching ? <div className="loader large">a</div> : <div>{children}</div>}
</div>
```

The loader SASS:

```
.loader {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  border: .5rem solid $grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: .5rem solid $loader-border-color;
  height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 7.2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  z-index: 10;

  &.large {
    height: 7rem;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 7rem;
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
}
```

My initial thought is that the loader div is being modified instead of removed and a new div created. I know I have two solutions to the problem but I would like to know why this is happening as the project uses a lot of ternary operators and it would be an inconvenience to replace them all.